# Angular Component testing - query by Component

Tags: angular, angular-test

When testing the DOM representation of a `@Component`, you're able to query its nested elements via its *fixture*

```js
fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.example'));
```

You can also filter by `@Directive`

```js
fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkDirectiveStub));
```

---

Now, let's say you have an inner `@Component` `NzButtonComponent` used like this

```js
<button nz-button>Example</button>
```

How can I precisely query for it? There is no `By.component(...)`.

Comment: Use a CSS attribute selector:  `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement,querySelector(['nz-button']) as HTMLButtonElement;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select by CSS attribute if you use the `nativeElement` instead of the `debugElement`:

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[nz-button]') as HTMLButtonElement;
```

For multiple elements the `querySelectorAll` method can be used.

Comment: Does this work even when there are multiple elements?

Comment: `nativeElement` also has the `querySelectorAll` method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `('[nz-button]')` ? Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## Query like directive

Possibly you can use

`fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(AnyComponent))` it returns `DebugElement` of that component

That works because in Angular Component inherits after Directive